# How can I remove all map object from HereMap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

How can I remove all map objects from HereMap ?

HereMap SDK only provide

```
- (BOOL)removeMapObject:(nonnull NMAMapObject *)object
- (BOOL)removeMapObjects:(nonnull NSArray<NMAMapObject *> *)objects
```

Comment: @VadimKotov Why did you remove tag ?

Comment: because this question is not specific to iPhone. It should be tagged with [tag:ios] instead. See description for [tag:iphone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely adding `NMAMapObject`'s to the map, I would suggest creating a mutable array of all objects added to the map, so when you do

```
//in viewDidLoad for instance create an empty NSMutableArray called mapObjects
[self.mapView addMapObject:self.mapRoute];
[mapObjects addObject:mapObject];
```

Then when you want to remove them all you will be able to do:

```
[self.mapView removeMapObject:mapObjects];
```

Let me know if that would work for you...

Comment: How can I find container. I did not create any container in my project. Can you please share some code How to create container from HereMap.

Comment: Are you adding object by yourself to the map or? Do you use a NMAMapView object to display the map?

Comment: I am using `[self.mapView addMapObject:self.mapRoute];` `self.mapView` object of `IBOutlet NMAMapView * _Nullable mapView;`

Comment: Chek my answer above

Comment: Ok, Let me try with array